# When is Z-Wave S2 Security Mandatory?

Tags: security, zwave

When Z-Wave had security problems last year, I was pleased to see it [announced](https://z-wavealliance.org/z-wave-alliance-announces-new-security-requirements-z-wave-certified-iot-devices/) that S2 Security would be mandatory for all new certifications as of April and that [they didn't back off](https://z-wavealliance.org/mandatory-security-implementation-z-wave-certified-iot-devices-takes-effect-today/) at that time.

So I figured now would the time to pick up some Z-Wave deadbolts, but as far as I can tell [none of them support S2 security](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/regions/2/categories/6/products).

Even devices newly certified as recently as 11/10/2017 [do not support S2](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/products/2682).

What's the real scoop on S2 security?  The attacks on older Z-Wave were devastating but I thought they were addressing the security concerns effectively.  I haven't been able to find much talk about this online.

Comment: From the product list you shared (https://products.z-wavealliance.org/regions/2/categories/6/products) I see "August Smart Lock Rev 3" and "Danalock V3-BTZU" do support  S2 security

Answer (score 4):

> What's the real scoop on S2 security?

I studied a number of products and corresponding Z-Wave Protocol Implementation Conformance Statement issued to these products.

Products that feature S2 Security are all built on Z-Wave Development Kit Version: 6.71.01 or above. For Example, refer two very similar products from same brand:

- The [Aeotec LED Bulb 6:Multi-Colour](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/products/2880), which bears a Z-Wave Certification Date: **3/23/2018**, does not support S2 as it is built on Z-Wave Development Kit Version: 6.51.09. The [conformance statement](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/products/2880/embedpics) mentions Z-Wave Development Kit Version.
- Whereas, the [Aeotec LED Bulb 6: Multi-White](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/products/2843), which bears a Z-Wave Certification Date: **3/16/2018**; supports S2 security as it is built on Z-Wave Development Kit Version: 6.71.01, as per the [conformance statement](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/products/2843/embedpics).

So, S2 Security availability is seemingly tied to Z-Wave Development Kit Version used and not the date device got certified. This pattern repeats itself across all product categories such as [locks](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/regions/2/categories/6/products), [lighting devices](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/regions/2/categories/5/products), [thermostats](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/regions/2/categories/10/products) etc.